# SecurityException vs UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: .net, exception, role-base-authorization

My application has role based security. When an user attempts to perform some operation, and the role he is in does not have that permission, we throw an exception.

```
void DeleteFile(String fileName) {
  if(!_role.canDeleteFile()) {
    throw new Exception();
  }

  //delete it
}
```

Now i was refactoring this code and find the usage if base `Exception` class ugly. Instance of what class should i use? Or should i subclass one?

### Edit

I searched in the framework and found two. but none of them actually fits. `SecurityException` seems to be part of BCL itself. `UnauthorizedAccessException` is under `IO` namespace. Which exception is the most appropriate *(to inherit from)* in this case?

Comment: As this is your own context for using exceptions, I would create my own exception class that inherits from Exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `UnauthorizedAccessException` is under the `IO` namespace it's typically used for file access etc.

`SecurityException` is the base exception in Code Access Security and is probably my first choice.